# Can we define this set?

Tags: logic, set-theory

1. Given an infinite set S in some universe U, construct the set of complementary pairs C: {{A,Ac}} where  A,Ac∈P(U), the power set of U, and  A or Ac is contained in S, not necessarily a proper subset of S. C is the image of a choice function on the set of all two-part partitions of U.
2. Assume a choice function g:C→P(U), g = {({A,Ac },B), B∈P(U))} that selects an arbitrary element B from {A,Ac}.
3. C':=g(C),  g({A,Ac}) = B∈P(U), C'={B}.
4. There exists a bijection h:C'→P(S), since elements of C' are either an element of P(S) or its complement in U, and each element of P(S) has a unique complement in U. So let h={(B,D), B∈C', D∈P(S), D an arbitrary element of P(S)}.
5. Assume there exists k:S→C', k(x) = B∈C' , so k={(x,B), x∈S, B∈C'}.
6. Define a function f:S→P(S), f(x) = h(k(x)), f = {(x,D), x∈S, D∈P(S)}.
7. Can we define ∗: ∈∗ ↔ ∉()?

[image]

Comment: Step 5 isn't well defined. Where did c come from, and how does it relate to x ?

Comment: I have a little problem with (2) but it may be trivial. C is a set of pairs (A, Ac). So g inputs the pair (A, Ac) and outputs either A or Ac. So g: C→ (). The target set is (, not U. Do I have that right? And does it make any difference to the rest of your idea?

Comment: Also in (3) what does g(C) mean? g inputs elements of C. The notation g(C) can only be the image of C by g, meaning the entire set of outputs as g ranges over the elements of C. This image is clearly is (). Am I missing something?

Comment: In (4), C' is more than bijective to (). C' = (). They're the same set. Yes? Again am I missing something?

Comment: (5) says k is a function from S to (), since I've convinced myself that C' = (). Then h is just the identity function, so f = k. (7) is just the last step of Cantor's theorem. We can certainly define S* as a subset of S, but assuming that S* gets hit by f leads to a contradiction, so f is not a surjection. This is all just a highly convoluted version of the proof of Cantor's theorem that there's no surjection from a set to its powerset. If I am following correctly.

Comment: Oh I see. It's getting late so I'm done for the night but I see what you're doing. For each set X ⊆ S, the set C contains both the pairs (X, Xc) and (Xc, X). But your choice function might have picked X each time. I'd have to re-do my analysis with that understanding but not tonight. We do have C* ⊆ ().

Comment: Ah then (4) is wrong. C* ⊆ () and you claim there's still a bijection between them. *Clearly this fails in the finite case*. Say S = {1, 2, 3}. The powerset contains the usual eight elements. Now say the choice function picks each of the subsets once, EXCEPT that from the pairs (∅, S) and (S, ∅) it picks ∅ twice. But in a set you can't repeat elements. So C* only has seven sets in it. In other words S is not in the image of g. Now I'm going to bed.

Comment: (∅,S) is only in C if S=U.

Comment: user4894- C* is not a subset of () since C* contains sets that have elements from outside S.

Comment: Graham Kemp- c is one of the sets in C' as chosen by g from each pair in the set of pairs C. The function k relates x to c.

Comment: @21stCenturyParadox Complements in U. My bad.

Comment: Ok now I think I have found a problem. When you say "Ac∈P(U)", the problem is that P(U) does not exist. That's because U is not a set. You stated this in a comment below: *When I reference U, I am thinking of U as the universe of sets whose elements are sets.* With that understanding, you may not form P(U) and none of the Ac are sets. The rest of the argument is gone. You can rescue this by stipulating that U is a set. Is that your intention?

Comment: user4894-yes, U is a set that contains S as a proper subset. It is not the set of all sets lest we fall into Russel's paradox.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Given a set  in some universe , construct the set of complementary pairs : {(,)} where ∈(), the power set of , and  is the complement of  in .

For an example, let U = {0, 1, 2} and S={0,1} . (Check:  S ⊆ U okay.)

Then we have P(S)={{},{0},{1},{0,1}} and C={({},{0,1,2}), ({0},{1,2}), ({1},{0,2}), ({0,1},{2})}

C ⊆ P(S) × P(U)

> 2. Assume a choice function : →  that selects an arbitrary element (either  or ) from each pair.

Not quite. Each pair consists of two subsets of U, not elements of U.  That selection would be g:C → P(U)

As we have a arbitrary g, Let us take, for instance, g={(({},{0,1,2}),{}), (({0},{1,2}),{0}), (({1},{0,2}),{0,2}), (({0,1},{2}),{2})}

> 3. Let () = ′.

I think you are trying to define C' to be the g image of C. Let C' := g(C)

For our example, C'={{},{0},{0,2},{2}} and generally C' ⊆ P(U)

> 4. There exists a bijection ℎ:′ → (), since elements of ′ are either an element of () or its complement in , and each element of () has a unique complement in .

Yes.  For every element c in C' there is a one-to-one correspondance with a subset s of S since c = s or c = sᶜ .  Warning: That is only the case as long as S is a *proper subset* of U ; to avoid the complements also being subsets of S.

Then in fact h = {(c,x)∈ C'×P(S): c=x or c=xᶜ} , the function which returns the subset of S corresponding to the element of C'.  Also h ={(c,x)∈ C'×P(S): c=g(x,xᶜ)}

> 5. Assume there exists : → ′, () =  ∈ ′.

This is not well defined.  You seem to want k: P(S) → C' , k(x) = g(x, xᶜ)

In fact k = {(x,c)∈ P(S)×C' : c=g(x,xᶜ)}

> 6. Define a function : → (), () = ℎ(()).

Uh... h(k(x))=x... and since it is the identity function for P(S), we have f:P(S)→P(S).

> Can we define ∗: ∈∗ ↔ ∉()?

... That would be S*={x∈P(S): x∉x} which means S* is actualy P(S)

Comment: Graham Kemp- I am sorry, I failed to specify at the start that I was making reference via S to an infinite set. I have edited the post to say so. When I reference U, I am thinking of U as the universe of sets whose elements are sets.

Comment: Graham Kemp- I put together a paper - notes from thinking about my question https://myopenmaths3.s3.amazonaws.com/ufiles/85516/alternation_3.pdf

Comment: Graham Kemp - h maps sets to sets, let me consider your note elated to h

Comment: Graham Kemp - did you man to type s where you typed x in notes under 4.?

Comment: regarding k(x) = g(x, xᶜ)...k(x)=c, (x, g(A,Ac)) where (A,Ac) ∈C and g(A,Ac) = c

Comment: OK- I have confused U with P(U)...So let U be the set you described, and P(U) its power set as you show under 3. But then h = {(c,A)∈ C'×P(S): c=A or c=Aᶜ, Aᶜ a set in P(U)}, is that correct?

Comment: So then k= {(x,c)∈ S×C' : c=g(A,Aᶜ)}, ...I'll work on this and edit the post.

Comment: So h = {(k(x),A)∈ C'×P(S)} , the function returns the subset of S corresponding to the element x of S by composition with k ...that is f(x). So then, can we define ∗: ∈∗ ↔ ∉()

Comment: When you say U is the universe of sets, do you mean the proper class of sets? So that U is not necessarily a set? Trying to understand your post now that I realize the complements are taken with respect to U. But that's very problematic because those complements are not necessarily sets. If you take S = the primes, the complement in the reals is all real numbers that aren't primes. That's a set. But the complement of the integers in the proper class of sets is every set that's not the positive integers. That's not a set. Am I understanding? If so, the complement is a set if and only if U is.

Answer (score 1):

*S* * is a well defined subset of *S* determined by the functions *g*, *h*, and *k*. However, it may be induced by a single function *f* : *S* → *P*(*S*) without any other reference, not even to *U*. *S* * (*f*) = {*x* ∈ *S* | *x* ∉ *f*(*x*)}.

To see why this is the case, let *C* be *P*(*S*) x {0,1}. Let *g* : *P*(*S*) → {0,1}. Let *h* be any bijection *P*(*S*) → *P*(*S*). Let *k* : *S* → *P*(*S*).

We define *C* and *g* in this way to simplify the problem. We may take (*A*, 0) to denote *A* and (*A*, 1) to denote *U*-*A*.

Then letting *x* ∈ *S*, we can see a series of transformations that parallels the process the poster describes:

*x* to (*k*(*x*), *g*(*k*(*x*))) = y to *h*(π_1(y)) = *h*(*k*(*x*)) = *f*(*x*). Or simply *x* to *f*(*x*).

Note that the function *g* does not influence *f* at all. Also, composition with a bijection can simply be thought of as a single function.

Below is an in-depth look at the the process the poster described.

1. I am assuming *U* is a set and not a proper class based on a comment I saw by the poster. Then we let *S* be a proper subset (proper by the same comment) of *U*. We then define *C* = {{*A*, *A*^c} ⊂ *P*(*U*) | *A* ⊂ *S*}.
2. Let *g* : *C* → *P*(*U*) be a choice function. That is for all *A* ⊂ *S*, *g*({*A*, *U*-*A*}) ∈ {*A*, *U*-*A*}. Note that we do not need to assume that one exists due to the fact that *g*' given by *g*'({*A*, *U*-*A*}) = *A* for all *A* ⊂ *S* is an explicit choice function (from *C* → *P*(*S*) ⊂ *P*(*U*)). Furthermore, any choice function is injective. Suppose *g*({*A*, *U*-*A*}) = *g*({*A*', *U*-*A*'}). Then *A* = *A*', *A* = *U*-*A*', *U*-*A* = *A*', or *U*-*A* = *U*-*A*'. In any case, we have that {*A*, *U*-*A*} = {*A*', *U*-*A*'}. We can then talk about *g*^(-1) : *g*(*C*) → *C*, which is also injective.
3. I will simply use *g*(*C*) (= {*B* ⊂ *U* | there exists an *A* ⊂ *S* such that *g*(*A*) = *B*}) in my notation.
4. There exists a bijection from *g*(*C*) → *P*(*S*). Let *B* ∈ *g*(*C*). Note that *g*'(*g*^(-1)(*B*)) = *B* if *B* ⊂ *S* and *U*-*B* if *U*-*B* ⊂ *S*. This is a composition of injective functions and is therefore injective. Now the surjectivity of *g*'∘*g*^(-1) comes from the fact that for every pair of elements *A*, *A*' ∈ *P*(*S*), {*A*, *U*-*A*} = {*A*', *U*-*A*'} implies that *A* = *A*' since *S* is a proper subset of *U*.
5. Again, we need not assume that such a function *k* : *S* → *g*(*C*) exists. In fact, *k*' given by *k*'(*x*) = *g*({{*x*}, *U*-{*x*}}) for all *x* ∈ *S* is an explicit (injective) function.
6. I will simply use *h*∘*k* : *S* → *P*(*S*) in my notation.
7. Let *S* * = {*x* ∈ *S* | *x* ∉ (*h*∘*k*)(*x*)}. This is well defined because *S*, *g*, *h*, and *k* are all well-defined.